# Responsive Jquery Feedback Slider

Tags: jquery

for the past 3 days i am searching in net for a jquery slider which looks like below image [image]

The content should move from right to left when the circle is dragged to right..

Can any one help me in finding this type of slider in responsive..

Comment: "how i can make one with OWL Carousel" I guess the best way is to ask their support directly.

Comment: Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bZf9g/) You can play with numbers as you desire.

Comment: @BatuZet Thanks for your fiddle its possible to coutomize input range